# Java RegEx Date Validation - Leap Year

Tags: java, regex, validation

I am working on a school assignment and I am just stuck with the logic on this. Basically need to validate a RegEx (date) of years between 1900 and 2099. The days cannot exceed the maximum month days; (ie. June has 30 days so 31 is invalid) as well as account for leap years where the February date can be 29. Here is what I have so far but I keep getting validation errors from when the code is ran in the TestHarness. I think I have way to much logic here but not sure how to resolve. Any help would be awesome.

```
    public class RegexValidator {
            //class variables
            private String DATE_REGEX = "^((19|20)\\d\\d)-(0?[1-9]|
            1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$";

    public RegexValidator() {
            m_datePattern.compile(DATE_REGEX);
    }

    public boolean validDate(String date) {

        Matcher matcher = m_datePattern.matcher(date);

        int year = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));//parse to calculate leap
        String month = matcher.group(2);
        String day = matcher.group(3);

        if(matcher.matches()) {
            matcher.reset();

            if(matcher.find()) {

                if(day.equals("31") && (month.equals("4") || month.equals("04") ||
                month.equals("6") || month.equals("06") || month.equals("9") ||
                month.equals("09") || month.equals("11"))) {
                    return false;
                } else if(month.equals("2") || month.equals("02")) {
                    //accounts for leap year
                    if(year % 4 == 0) {
                        if(day.equals("30") || day.equals("31")) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(day.equals("29") || day.equals("30") || day.equals("31")) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Here is a list of the errors I am getting:

```
    Error validating date '1900-1-11'

Error validating date '1900-1-11'

 ---- test date 1892-02-29 - expected false
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
 ---- test date 1976-02-29 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '1976-02-29'

Error validating date '1976-02-29'

 ---- test date 2001-02-29 - expected false
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
 ---- test date 2002-13-02 - expected false
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
 ---- test date 2003-01-31 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '2003-01-31'

Error validating date '2003-01-31'

 ---- test date 1964-03-31 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '1964-03-31'

Error validating date '1964-03-31'

 ---- test date 1965-4-31 - expected false
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
 ---- test date 1954-4-30 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '1954-4-30'

Error validating date '1954-4-30'

 ---- test date 1901-5-33 - expected false
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
 ---- test date 1901-5-15 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '1901-5-15'

Error validating date '1901-5-15'

 ---- test date 2016-05-31 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '2016-05-31'

Error validating date '2016-05-31'

 ---- test date 2006-06-31 - expected false
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
 ---- test date 20016-06-29 - expected false
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
 ---- test date 1934-7-4 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '1934-7-4'

Error validating date '1934-7-4'

 ---- test date 2016-07-31 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '2016-07-31'

Error validating date '2016-07-31'

 ---- test date 2011-8-19 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '2011-8-19'

Error validating date '2011-8-19'

 ---- test date 2111-8-31 - expected false
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
 ---- test date 2011-09-30 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '2011-09-30'

Error validating date '2011-09-30'

 ---- test date 2111-9-31 - expected false
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
 ---- test date 2011-10-1 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '2011-10-1'

Error validating date '2011-10-1'

 ---- test date 2111-10-31 - expected false
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
 ---- test date 2001-10-31 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '2001-10-31'

Error validating date '2001-10-31'

 ---- test date 2111-10-33 - expected false
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
 ---- test date 2111-11-30 - expected false
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
 ---- test date 2013-11-30 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '2013-11-30'

Error validating date '2013-11-30'

 ---- test date 2111-11-31 - expected false
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
 ---- test date 2011-12-31 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '2011-12-31'

Error validating date '2011-12-31'

 ---- test date 2099-12-31 - expected true
 ---- Exception calling validDate: null
Error validating date '2099-12-31'

Error validating date '2099-12-31'
```

Comment: Are the errors a secret?

Comment: They are not.. thanks for pointing that out. I have added them to the original question.

Comment: Well, one problem I spot right away is that `matcher.group(2)` returns the second group, which will be 19 or 20, _not_ the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `m_datePattern` is a `Pattern`, you're using `compile` incorrectly.  The signature of compile is

```
public static Pattern compile(String regex)
```

Since it's `static`, it does not apply to an instance; it's normally called like

```
Pattern.compile(regex)
```

Using a `Pattern` object instead of the class name makes no difference.  Thus, if `p` is a `Pattern` object, then:

```
p.compile(regex)
```

does the exact same thing as `Pattern.compile(regex)`, even if `p` is `null`.
The object is ignored.

Finally, `compile` **returns** a `Pattern`, which means the result has to be assigned to a `Pattern` object:

```
pat = Pattern.compile(Regex);
```

Your code doesn't assign it anywhere.  So the resulting pattern is just thrown away.

Finally, when you use `group(n)`, the groups, starting at 1, are the capture groups beginning with the first `(`, second `(`, etc., in the regex.  Your regex is

```
"^((19|20)\\d\\d)-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"
```

In this regex, `group(1)` is the year; `group(2)` is 19 or 20; `group(3)` is the month, and `group(4)` is the day.  Your code is using the wrong groups for the month and day.  Either change the numbers, or designate `(19|20)` as a *non-capture* group like this:

```
"^((?:19|20)\\d\\d)-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"
```

Now it won't be counted as one of the capture groups.

There may be other errors in your code.  These are just the ones I noticed.

Comment: Thank you all for you help. Each of your answers actually helped a portion of what I had wrong. The grouping error was key and also that I was using matcher.group before matcher.matches or matches.find. However, after fixing those errors I was still not passing the test. As @ajb mentioned, my patterns where being ignored because I was not actually assigning them.

Answer (score 1):

There are in fact numerous things wrong with this code. Here are the ones that I've been able to spot:

1. You're using `matcher.group` before `matcher.matches` or `matches.find`. This is illegal and throws `IllegalStateException` (see JavaDoc for this method [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-)).
2. `(19|20)` is also a matching group, so group 2 will not correspond to the month, as you seem to assume, but to first two digits of the year.
3. Your algorithm for checking leap years is too simple. Consider:

   ```
   @Test
   public void leapYearTricky() {
       Assert.assertFalse(new RegexValidator().validDate("1900-02-29"));
   }
   ```

Also, not an error *per se*, but what's the point of `matcher.matches`, `matcher.reset`, `matcher.find`? Why isn't `matcher.matches()` enough?

Answer (score 1):

I have a better solution (with Leap year):

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_REG_EXP = "(^(((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[\\/](0[1-9]|1[012]))|((29|30|31)[\\/](0[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[\\/](0[4,6,9]|11)))[\\/](19|[2-9][0-9])\\d\\d$)|(^29[\\/]02[\\/](19|[2-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)";

@Test
    public void testCheckValidateDate() {
        Assert.assertFalse("Wrong date, january do not have 32 days.", "32/01/2016".matches(DATE_FORMAT_REG_EXP));
        Assert.assertFalse("Wrong date, February do not have 30 days.", "30/02/2016".matches(DATE_FORMAT_REG_EXP));
        Assert.assertFalse("Wrong date, 2017 is not Leap year so 28 days", "29/02/2017".matches(DATE_FORMAT_REG_EXP));
        Assert.assertFalse("Wrong date, november have 30 days.", "31/11/2016".matches(DATE_FORMAT_REG_EXP));
        Assert.assertFalse("Wrong date, 16 instead of 2016.", "30/11/16".matches(DATE_FORMAT_REG_EXP));

        Assert.assertTrue("Good date.", "31/01/2016".matches(DATE_FORMAT_REG_EXP));
        Assert.assertTrue("Good date, 2016 is Leap year so 29 days", "29/02/2016".matches(DATE_FORMAT_REG_EXP));
        Assert.assertTrue("Good date.", "28/02/2016".matches(DATE_FORMAT_REG_EXP));
        Assert.assertTrue("Good date.", "28/02/2017".matches(DATE_FORMAT_REG_EXP));
        Assert.assertTrue("Good date.", "30/11/2016".matches(DATE_FORMAT_REG_EXP));
    }
```

**Démo:**

[Regexp](https://regex101.com/r/csydaS/1) - [java](https://regex101.com/r/csydaS/1/codegen?language=java) - [javascript](https://regex101.com/r/csydaS/1/codegen?language=javascript) - [php](https://regex101.com/r/csydaS/1/codegen?language=php) - [python](https://regex101.com/r/csydaS/1/codegen?language=python) - [C#](https://regex101.com/r/csydaS/1/codegen?language=csharp) - [ruby](https://regex101.com/r/csydaS/1/codegen?language=ruby) - [rust](https://regex101.com/r/csydaS/1/codegen?language=rust) - [goland](https://regex101.com/r/csydaS/1/codegen?language=golang) - [perl](https://regex101.com/r/csydaS/1/codegen?language=perl)